# How can I evaluate an array of multidimensional functions in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 6x3 array of functions, `dens`, in Matlab, in which each function has a two-dimensional vector `z` as input. I need to evaluate these functions at `z=[2 3]`, all at the same time; I have tried

```
ev_dens = @(z) cellfun(@(myfun) myfun(z),dens,'UniformOutput',false);
z =[2 3];
ev_dens(z)
```

but I got this error

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
Error in ==> @(myfun)myfun(z)
Error in ==> @(z)cellfun(@(myfun)myfun(z),dens,'UniformOutput',false)
```

Could you help me?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem, what is dens? Using some dummy data (`dens(1:6,1:3)={@(x)([x(2),x(1)+x(2)])}`) I don't get any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the following example data:

```
f{1,1} = @(z)([z(1),z(1)])
f{1,2} = @(z)([z(1),z(2)])
f{2,1} = @(z)([z(2),z(1)])
f{2,2} = @(z)([z(2),z(2)])

z = [2,3];
```

Your method works fine:

```
cellfun(@(F)F(z), f,'UniformOutput',false)
```

So it sounds like perhaps you have an error in one of your functions in `dens`. Try a nested for loop and see where you error:

```
for ii = 1:size(dens,1)
    for jj = 1:size(dens,2)
        dens{ii,jj}(z)
    end
end
```

and then check the values of `ii` and `jj` after you get your error, the function at `dens{ii,jj}` has an error in it.

---

In order to correct for the issue you mention in the comments (i.e. some of your cell elements are empty (i.e. `[]`), run this function first to convert your empty cells into function that output empty cells:

```
dens(cellfun(@isempty,dens)) = {@(z)([])}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; I have finally discovered the problem in my code: inside the array of functions I have some cells=[]. The problem is that I cannot predict where the [] cells will be and I cannot delete them. Do you know a way to overcome this issue? I would like to get 0 or [] in arrayfun in correspondence to these cells.

Comment: how about calling this first `dens(cellfun(@isempty,dens)) = {@(z)([])}`